# Why do my <input type="text"> elements change size when clicked into on smartphone?

Tags: javascript, css

If you click in them on [this webpage](http://railway-games.cyou/til/mitternachtsformel.html) with a mobile device, they become smaller. How could I stop it?

Has it something to do with my CSS style section?

Comment: What is the issue, and could you put some code directly here? It would be a great help :)

Answer (score 1):

Add inside `<head></head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```

Comment: Did I do it right? It didn't work :(

Comment: change css `input` `font-size` on absolute value now it `font-size: 3vh;` change to `font-size: 16px;`

Comment: I did also that and it still changes size if I click on it with my phone.

Answer (score 0):

And it in 
and add what types of style you want to add . in css file
you have to also use the @media query .

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: I added it in the <head> </head> but it didn't work